# Помогите разобраться с селекторами jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сделал простое выпадающее меню на jQuery, при ховере на ссылке, должен выезжать спрятанный див:

```
<a href="#">
    Link
</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    Content
</div>
```

Как выбрать идущий за ссылкой див, чтобы выезжал див, который находится возле ссылки и чтобы скрипт работал с неограниченным количеством этих ссылок?

```
$(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $('div').slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

И хотел спросить на какое событие лучше повесить исчезновение этого меню?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).next('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('.dropdown').bind("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Применил Ваш код, нужно убрать slideToggle и применить slideUp/Down иначе при хувере срабатывает, плюс закрытие не удачное потому что работает только если курсор войдет в зону контейнера, но в контейнере может быть другие элементы (например ссылки) наведя на которых сработает mouseout для контейнера.

Comment: Нужно проверять на вложенность элементов, Вы предоставили пример, в котором нет других элементов.
Т.е. при отведении мыши, нужно проверять, есть ли выше элемент .dropdown, если есть - то не закрывать, если нет - то закрывать.